# Conditional variable error when trying to open serialized Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp

I have the following model:

```
embedding_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, 100))
for word, i in text_tokenizer.word_index.items():
    embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size,
                            100,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=50,
                            trainable=False)

sequence_input = Input(shape=(50,), dtype='int32')
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

text_cnn = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(embedded_sequences)
text_cnn = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(text_cnn)
text_cnn = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(text_cnn)


text_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(text_cnn)
text_lstm = Dense(128, activation='relu')(text_lstm)
text_lstm = Dropout(0.3)(text_lstm)


char_in = Input(shape=(50, 18, ))
char_cnn = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(char_in)
char_cnn = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(char_cnn)
char_cnn = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')(char_cnn)

char_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(char_cnn)
char_lstm  = GaussianNoise(0.50)(char_lstm)
char_lstm = Dense(128, activation='relu')(char_lstm)
char_lstm = Dropout(0.3)(char_lstm)

merged = concatenate([char_lstm, text_lstm]) 

merged_d1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(merged)
merged_d1 = Dropout(0.3)(merged_d1)
merged_d1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(merged_d1)
merged_d1  = GaussianNoise(0.30)(merged_d1)

text_class = Dense(len(y_unique), activation='softmax')(merged_d1)
model = Model([sequence_input,char_in], text_class)
```

Trained with a GPU like such:

```
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)
parallel_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                       optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
parallel_model.fit([x_train, x_train_char], y_train, validation_data=([x_test, x_test_char], y_test), epochs=1 ,batch_size=512)
```

I serialize it with the `model.save()` method.

When I try to load it on the same machine in a different kernel, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Initializer for variable conv1d_4_1/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.
```

I'm not sure what loop or conditional it can be referring to, maybe something to do with the Bidirectional wrapper? I've serialized other similar models without any issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!